# How to check if mail is already registered (PHP)

Tags: php

Im new at this and I need help from u. I have this code but the problem is that if I try to register an email that is already registered it creates a new user without saying nothing. Thanks!

```
<?php
  require 'database.php';
    
  $message = '';

  if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['confirm_password'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users  (nombre, email, password, confirm_password) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :password, :confirm_password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $confirm_password = password_hash($_POST['confirm_password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':confirm_password', $confirm_password);
    
    if($_POST["password"] === $_POST["confirm_password"]) {
        if ($stmt->execute()){
            $message = 'Se ha creado un usuario satisfactoriamente';
        }else {
            $message = 'Lamentablemente ha ocurrido un error';
        }
    } else{
        $message = 'Las contraseñas no coinciden';
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: You have multiple approaches here. You can query the database to check if the mail is already there and/or use UNIQUE index for column email.

Comment: Your not echoing any thing out.